# How to get http_request metrics for non spring boot application

Tags: httprequest, metrics, prometheus-java

I'm trying to get metrics data using micrometer. But it's providing all JVM related metrics in the /metrics end point, but it's not providing **http_request** metrics.

We have exposed few API's and we are not able to measure the performance of it.

Anyone have an suggestion or workaround to get the http_request data into /metrics?